# Has Apple officially not allowed access to camera for app in background?

Tags: ios, iphone, avfoundation, ios-camera

Can I build an iOS app that uses the camera (even if it doesn't take pictures/video) while the app is in the background?

If not, why? Where has Apple come out with this information? **I have seen similar questions and answers, but none with direct proof from Apple.**

For example, if I wanted to make an app that, while in background, can keep track of how many trees our phone encounters through the day through object recognition software.

Comment: Did the answer help?

Comment: I still don't know Apple's reasoning (from their words, not our reasoning)

Comment: @micheal I have already attached link to apple doc in my answer.

Comment: Yes, it's a link to apple doc, which still didn't give me the "why"

Comment: assume a privacy reason. They dont want spy apps that record while not even "visible".

Answer (score 3):

The camera stops functioning when app moves to background and I have found this apple doc that supports the claim. Hope this will help you.

[AVCaptureSessionInterruptionReasonVideoDeviceNotAvailableInBackground](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avcapturesessioninterruptionreason/avcapturesessioninterruptionreasonvideodevicenotavailableinbackground?language=objc)

> Camera usage is prohibited while in the background. If you attempt to
>   start running a camera while in the background, the capture session
>   sends an AVCaptureSessionWasInterruptedNotification with this
>   interruption reason. If you don't explicitly call the stopRunning
>   method, your startRunning request is preserved, and when your app
>   comes back to foreground, you receive
>   AVCaptureSessionInterruptionEndedNotification and your session starts
>   running.

Answer (score 1):

No, as soon as your app enters the background (even the built-in camera app), the camera stops recording.

This is done primarily because the camera consumes a great deal of power and generates a lot of heat. If you were to record a 15 minute video with an iPhone, you will notice both pretty quickly.

Combine running CV software, and you will drain the battery of any device in short order.

Comment: Would the process of recording (but not saving) still consume a similar amount of power? I have no need for saving. Also, back to my original question, have you seen any documentation regarding this from Apple?

Comment: Not seeing anything in the official AVFoundation documentation, but there is a similar question with more background here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24428416/support-for-background-recording-of-video-using-avcapturesession. If the official Apple camera app cannot do something, that usually is a good indication third party developers also cannot.

Comment: The display would consume additional power, so one might argue that recording without display actually saves power.

Answer (score 1):

It's good that apple doesn't allow because it increases risk of apps capturing your moments from background without making you notice. Thus risk to privacy.